# Javascript conflicting with html anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I'm currently creating a [website](http://gradallservice.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/equipment.html#gradalls) which has a persistent header and footer. To cut down on code duplication, I use jquery to load the header.html and footer.html when each different page is loaded.

Each html page which uses this header and footer, loads it with the code below.

```
<!-- Header and footer loading -->
<script> 
  $(function() {
    $("#header").load("header.html"); 
    $("#footer").load("footer.html");
  });
</script>

<div id="header">
  (header.html content rendered here)
</div>
```

The best way to explain this next part is by going to the site I have linked. What I would like to do is have the drop down button take a user to the specific section of the equipment page from any other page on the website. As you can currently see, this function only works if the user is already on the equipment page.

From everything I've read, cross page anchors should be setup the same way as in-page anchors. Use `<a href="equipment.html#anchorname></a>` and then link it to the page with `<a id="anchorname></a>`. However, this approach is only working when the user is on the same page as the anchor. I'm pretty sure this is due to the timing of anchor mechanism and when the jQuery code runs.

My two questions are...

1. Could someone explain the sequence of events that are taking place which are causing my anchor not to work.
2. What do I need to do in order to get my cross-site anchors to work properly?

Thanks and let me know if you need specific code snippets or have any questions.

Comment: I didn't go into the site, create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here if you want further assistance BUT, an anchor is not part of the URL, it's processed on the client side and the broswer controls it's behavior. You can capture that in script and do whatever you like. There is no issue with "anchoring" a link, and it has nothing to do with ids. 1 potential problem you have (if that's not a typo) is that your id attribute in the a tag isn't closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cross-page anchors are working exactly as intended. Consider your base HTML page with JavaScript disabled:

[image: the page]

Then `#gradalls` or `#trucks` will "scroll" to that respective anchor immediately. I say "scroll" because there is not enough content to scroll anywhere - the page will just sit there, stationary.

Next, your series of jQuery load events will fire like so:

```
$(function() {
  $("#header").load("header.html"); 
  $("#footer").load("footer.html");
  $("#xl4100-99").load("xl4100_99.html");
  $("#xl4200-95").load("xl4200_95.html");
  $("#lowboy-93").load("lowboy_93.html");
  $("#gmctruck-93").load("gmctruck_93.html");
});
```

They will populate various containers in your page and the content will grow downwards, however, the page will not scroll. That has *already* happened.

### Solution 1

The best solution, and SEO friendly one, is to simply include the content in each page and *not* dynamically load it in. In fact, in addition to your keywords, a [search engine simulator](http://www.webconfs.com/search-engine-spider-simulator.php) will only see

> Dave Ankney Gradall Equipment Gradalls Trailers Trucks

and no links whatsoever. Then it may go away for a long time because there was nothing *juicy* there. Since you are using S3, you have to manually include the content in each page.

### Solution 2

Either that, or use a proper server backend like PHP, in which case you can just include each part of the HTML like so:

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="header"><?php include("header.php"); ?>
    </div>
```

(Only *rename* header.html to header.php)

### Solution 3

If you really just want to get the jump to work, you can change your JS like so:

```
<!-- Header and footer loading -->
<script>
$(function() {
  // Create Deferred instances that can be handed to $.when()
  var d1 = $.Deferred();
  var d2 = $.Deferred();
  // var d3 = 
  // var d4 = 

  // Set up a chain of events
  $.when(d1, d2).then(function() {
    // When everything has loaded, jump to the fragment
    var hash = window.location.hash
    if (hash !== "") {
      window.location.hash = hash;
    }
  });

  // Perform the load calls
  $("#header").load("header.html", function() { d1.resolve(); });
  $("#footer").load("footer.html", function() { d2.resolve(); });
  // ...
});
</script>
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: great writeup! When I added the jQuery to the page, I was weary that it might conflict with scrapers. For some reason I thought the content of the header and footer were "scrapable" but after double checking, you're right. Obviously, one of the main functions for this site is too attract customers via the web so I'm going to have to rethink my use of jQuery. This will only be a static site, so that cuts out the php option. I think you're first suggestion is the most practical. Are there any other options to cut down on code/html reuse in this situation, or do I need to just bite the bullet?

Comment: Thanks. Now, back in the old days when not many people seriously used server-side coding, we used tools like Dreamweaver to generate static HTML files with menu headers. But, for every change we would have to start up DW and reupload many touched files. Painful.

Comment: You'll want a server-side solution, maybe even a CMS like WordPress to make this so easy. Plus, for SEO considerations you'll want your own domain name, and shorter the better (your site is basically an extension of Amazon as Google sees it). There are all-in-one providers that handle everything, or at least give you server-tools like PHP. I use GoDaddy for my small sites.

Answer (score 0):

it might help you

read the url and split the url on hash tag after complete loading of page call the below method....

```
function scrollTo(hash) {
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
}
```